# How to handle Django Pagination with Nested tabs

Tags: python, html, django, pagination

I want to add pagination to my template,My template have Nested Tab(see code), all My inner tabs contain a table and i want to add pagination to all my tables in my inner tabs.

I have so far added pagination to one of my table and it works but the problem is whenever page refresh it goes my to first tab `<!-- overview-->` , not the one that made the request, although pagination is working.

This is the structure of my tabs.I am not using custom JS or CSS, only BS4 class

```html
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
   <!--OVERVIEW TAB-->
   <!--STATIC TAB-->
       <!--TAB 1-->
       <!--TAB 2-->
   <!-- FILES TAB-->
       <!--TAB 1 -->
       <!--TAB 2 -->
       <!--TAB 3 -->
   <!--Registry TAB -->
       <!--TAB 1 -->
       <!--TAB 2 -->
   <!--Network TAB-->
       <!--TAB 1 -->
       <!--TAB 2 -->
       <!--TAB 3 -->
</div>
```

[image]

**TEMPLATE.html**

```html
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
           {% if strings.has_other_pages %}
           <ul class="pagination justify-content-center pagination-lg">
              {% if strings.has_previous %}
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1">First</a> </li>
              {% endif %}

              {% for i in strings.paginator.page_range %}
                 {% if strings.number == i %}
             <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                 {% elif i > strings.number|add:'-3' and i < strings.number|add:'3' %}
             <li><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                 {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}

              {% if strings.has_next %}
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ strings.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a> </li>
              {% endif %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
</nav>
```

**views.py**

```py
def viewable(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

        strings = [ 'a','b','c'] #There are about 2000 entries in this list

 #STRING PAGE PAGINATOR
        stringspaginator = Paginator(strings,100)
        try:
            strings = stringspaginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            strings = stringspaginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            strings = stringspaginator.page(stringspaginator.num_pages)

         return render(request, 'viewable.html', {"metadata" : metadata,
                                                 "folders_created": folders_created,
                                                 "files_created": files_created ,
                                                 "files_deleted":files_deleted,
                                                "registry_written":registry_written,
                                                 "registry_deleted": registry_deleted,
                                                 "http":http,
                                                 "tcp":tcp,
                                                 "udp":udp,
                                                 'positives': positives,
                                                 'negatives': negatives,
                                                 'libs': libs,
                                                 'strings': strings
                                                 })
```

Now my understanding is i should add tab in my GET request that is making the request and based upon that it should redirect to proper tab, but i have no idea how. or even if that is the right solution.

> I am sending a lots of variables to my template that is then displayed in multiple tables, i don't think this is the best solution for handling that much amount of data but i am a beginner and right now that the only way i know .

Answer (score 0):

So, since i got no response and it think, it might be difficult to handle using server, i used [DataTables JS](https://www.datatables.net/) for the solution. Its fast efficient and have many great options for table customization. So i recommend that.